# Layout with multiple responsive and fixed boxes

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create the following layout. The important thing is, this is an application and should always fill the available room.

There are some boxes that need to grow in size when the window grows and some need to stay the same. I'm not quite sure if this is even possible with html5. Assume this should only work on a modern browser (so no IE).

Here is the layout I want to create. The arrows indicate whether the box can grow in that direction.

[image]

This is what I was able to get so far. The big problem is that box 3 and 4 are not as big as possible.

[My try](http://jsfiddle.net/BZd2E/)

```
<div class="fixed-right-col" style="width: 300px; margin-right: 20px; min-height: 100%; float: right;">
    <div style="height: 200px; background-color: gray;">
        2
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: olive; bottom: 500px;">
        4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="width: auto; min-height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Probleme + Menü -->
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6" style="background: red; min-height: 300px">1</div>
        <div class="span6" style="background: aqua; min-height: 300px;">1</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Chat + Userlist -->
    <div class="row-fluid" style="min-height: 100%;">
        <div class="span12" style="background: green; height: auto;">
            <div style="height: auto;">3</div>
            <input type="text" style="width: auto;" value="5">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a specific source order the elements must be in?  Or is whatever will work ok?

Comment: Whatever works is ok :) I have no idea where to start or how one generally approaches such a problem.

Comment: Can you find an example or two of something you're looking for?  How about something like this? http://beta2.mybattlereport.com/collective.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to decide on how you want to group your elements.  Both of these solutions use Flexbox.  You could recreate this using `display: table/table-row/table-cell` elements, but it would take a *lot* of extra elements to do so.

## (1, 1, 2) ((3, 5), 4)

This grouping makes sense if elements 1, 1, and 2 are part of a header element.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/kihgd

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="group1">
    <div class="a">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="a">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      2
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="group2a">
      <article class="c">
        3
      </article>
      <footer class="e">
        5
      </footer>
    </div>
    <aside class="d">
      4
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

/* group 1, the header */
header.group1 {
  display: flex;
  height: 10em;
  background: yellow;
  padding: .5em;
}

.a {
  flex: 1 auto;
  background: aqua;
  margin: .5em;
}

.b {
  width: 10em;
  background: grey;
  margin: .5em;
}

/* group 2 */
.group2 {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  margin: .5em;
}

.group2a {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

article.c {
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
  margin: .5em;
}

footer.e {
  height: 5em;
  background: green;
  margin: .5em;
}

aside.d {
  width: 10em;
  background: olive;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

## ((1, 1), 3, 5), (2, 4)

This grouping makes sense if elements 2 and 4 are part of a sidebar.  This grouping requires very little modification to make it fit into narrower viewports:  just hide the display property on `.container`.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/GCrFa

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <header class="group1">
    <div class="a">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="a">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      2
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="group2">
    <div class="group2a">
      <article class="c">
        3
      </article>
      <footer class="e">
        5
      </footer>
    </div>
    <aside class="d">
      4
    </aside>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

/* group 1, the header */
header.group1 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  height: 10em;
  background: yellow;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.a {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 auto;
  -ms-flex: 1 auto;
  flex: 1 auto;
  background: aqua;
  margin: .5em;
}

.b {
  width: 10em;
  background: grey;
  margin: .5em;
}

/* group 2 */
.group2 {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  padding: .5em;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.group2a {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -moz-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

article.c {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
  margin: .5em;
}

footer.e {
  height: 5em;
  background: green;
  margin: .5em;
}

aside.d {
  width: 10em;
  background: olive;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

Browser support should include Chrome, Opera, Firefox (usually requires adding an explicit width anywhere that `display: -moz-box` is used), IE10, Safari.  http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: Great solution. Didn't know about flexbox before. Took me some time to understand it but now I love it!

Answer (score 0):

One of the best things to use in your layout will be the 'calc' method, allowing you to set a width to be as such:

```
.calcWidth {
    width: 100% - 200px;
}
```

used as:

```
.calcWidth {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px); /* Firefox */
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px); /* Chrome / Safari */
}
```

This will allow you to reserve space on your page for a fixed size element and keep another part of a page responsive while taking up the entire viewing width.  The calc method will work with other properties.

Comment: Calc() is not supported by Opera, Android, or older iOS:  http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc